# Spring security with Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring-security

I have the spring security redirecting to the login page whenever the user is not authenticated with

```
<form-login login-page="/login/"
    authentication-failure-handler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
    authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"         
    username-parameter="j_username" 
    password-parameter="j_password"
    login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
    always-use-default-target="false" />
```

But now I have an AJAX call that can return this login page. Is it possible instead of return the login page, when the call is made using ajax, to return the 401?

Thanks

Comment: 404 is for page/resource not found.  Why would you return that for an unauthenticated user? Maybe you mean 401?

Comment: yes you are right!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the solution. Doing this https://gist.github.com/bmchild/5569833 I have the 401 if the request is ajax and redirect to login otherwise